# Maximize connectivity probability with a number of edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, approximation-algorithms

We are given a graph $G$, whose edges are either *open* or *closed*. Initially all the edges are closed. For each edge $e$, if we choose to *activate* it, then after the activation, it becomes open with probability $p_e$. Given a pair of nodes $(s,t)$, we seek a subset of edges to activate to maximize the probability that $s$ and $t$ are connected, subject to the constraint that we can activate at most $C$ edges. Another formulation is to find a subset of edges to activate with minimum number of edges, subject to the constraint that the probability that $s$ and $t$ are connected is at least $P$. My questions are: is this problem related to some known combinatorial graph problem? How to design algorithms solving it?

Comment: After you activate an edge, do you get to know if it opened or not, before you choose the next edge to activate? Or do you first activate all edges?

Comment: No, just suppose that we are doing the provisioning by optimizing the expected connectivity probability.